# regex to allow 2 specific subdomains

Tags: php, regex

Currently I am allowing for with or without www. I need to add allow for an additional subdomain:

```
#http://site.com,
#http://www.site.com,
#http://embed.site.com
```

Here what I have currently:

```
#https?://(www\.)?site\.com/video/.*#i
```

Comment: Can't really understand your question. Can you elaborate your examples with some expected output for some input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
#https?://((?:www|embed)\.)?site\.com/video/.*#i
```